# How to use whenever gem to run a task at 2 am AND 2 pm?

Tags: ruby, cron, whenever

Currently I run this code:

```
every 1.day, at: '2am' do
  rake 'data:load_direct_monitoring_statistics'
end if @environment == 'production'
every 1.day, at: '2pm' do
  rake 'data:load_direct_monitoring_statistics'
end if @environment == 'production'
```

This code works as intended, but: is there a way to use just **one** cron declaration to cover both cases?

Comment: Your question did not fit very well within the framework of Code Review in its current form, as you are asking a specific programming question, rather than a general review of your code. See [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for reference. We elected to migrate it to Stack Overflow for this reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to test in whenever repository you should be able to pass Array

```
every "weekday", :at => %w(5:02am 3:52pm) do
```

Here is the source> https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/334cfa01f373006cc032e23907b1777a8ea3f3b0/test/functional/output_at_test.rb

So in you case it should be ok to do like

```
every 1.day, at: ['2am','2pm'] do
  rake 'data:load_direct_monitoring_statistics'
end if @environment == 'production'
```